# Why does this command fail when run with "-Hostname 127.0.0.1" but not when I run it directly?

Tags: powershell

I'm having a hard time understanding why these commands fail when run remotely. Here is an example run of my executing the command directly, via invoke-command and via invoke-command with a "remote" host. The latter set fails.

```
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> & 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe' "--start"
zabbix_agentd.exe [16608]: service [Zabbix Agent] started successfully
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
True
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> & 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe' "--stop"
zabbix_agentd.exe [20428]: service [Zabbix Agent] stopped successfully
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
True
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> invoke-command -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--start" }
zabbix_agentd.exe [10976]: service [Zabbix Agent] started successfully
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
True
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> invoke-command -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--stop" }
zabbix_agentd.exe [17096]: service [Zabbix Agent] stopped successfully
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
True
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> invoke-command -computername 127.0.0.1 -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--start" }
zabbix_agentd.exe [8508]: service [Zabbix Agent] started successfully
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (zabbix_agentd.e...ed successfully:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 127.0.0.1

PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
False
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> invoke-command -computername 127.0.0.1 -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--stop" }
zabbix_agentd.exe [12384]: service [Zabbix Agent] stopped successfully
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (zabbix_agentd.e...ed successfully:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 127.0.0.1

PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $?
False
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  666


PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent>
```

Shouldn't the program run exactly the same? I note that the programs still execute correctly, but they somehow produce this seemingly spurious error. I don't imagine this is an environment problem.

I should also say that if I pass the "--help" option to zabbix_agentd.exe instead of "--start" or "--stop" it seems to work fine; I get a string showing the help text and no error.

EDIT: One potential clue might be that zabbix_agentd.exe (inexplicably) sends its success messages to stderr. The remote runner for windows may just interpret any such output as a sign of failure and react accordingly. I'm playing with that, but a quick 2>&1 doesn't seem to solve the problem.

EDIT: Probably also worth noting that zabbix_agentd.exe properly returns a 0 on success.

```
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> invoke-command -computername 127.0.0.1 -scriptblock { & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--start"; $LASTEXITCODE };
zabbix_agentd.exe [19564]: service [Zabbix Agent] started successfully
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (zabbix_agentd.e...ed successfully:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 127.0.0.1

0
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent>
```

Comment: Don't use `$?` for external executables.. use `$LASTEXITCODE`

Comment: The values of $? and $LASTEXITCODE are secondary in my mind. My real goal is to try an understand why there is an error here at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would seem that powershell converts any stderr output into an ErrorRecord object automatically. This also happens locally, but just doesn't show up as an exception:

```
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> & 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe' "--start"
zabbix_agentd.exe [19948]: service [Zabbix Agent] started successfully
PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent>

---

PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent> ( & 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe' "--start" 2>&1 ).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     ErrorRecord                              System.Object


PS C:\Users\guy\Downloads\zabbix_agent>
```

I confirmed in the Zabbix source code that it's just printing to stderr and not doing anything more exotic.

When running remotely, powershell doesn't display the text version, but the entire exception object.

So, the error was always there, but not visible as such.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want the Boolean, add 'return $?' to your scriptblock.

```
$returnedBoolean = invoke-command -computername 127.0.0.1 -scriptblock {
    & "C:\Program Files\Zabbix\zabbix_agentd.exe" "--stop"
    return $?
}
$returnedBoolean
```